# PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error, I tried going through other similar threads but it didn't help.

here is php

```
$host = "http://www.example.net";
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "aaa";
$password = "sss";
$userstable = "ddd";
$dbName = "fff";

if ($url != $host){
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName);
//@mysqli_select_db("$dbName");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$query = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $userstable where(url = '$url')"));

if ($query == false){
$hits = "1";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO $userstable (url,hits) VALUES('$url','$hits')";
}
else {
$hitquery =  "SELECT `hits` FROM $userstable where url = '$url'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $hitquery);
$hits = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, 0,  'hits');
//$hits = mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT `hits` FROM $userstable where url = '$url'"), 0,  "hits");
$query2 = "UPDATE $userstable SET `hits` = hits+1 where url = '$url'";
}
mysqli_query($con, $query2);
}
if(!$url) {
$url =  "$host";
}
```

**eror generate on line 157**

```
$hits = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, 0,  'hits');
```

How to fix this mysqli?

Comment: What you want to do? `$hits = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`. What should other params to do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: try : $hits = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: @AbraCadaver can you help write some fix code?

Comment: @astack The error message is telling what you are doing wrong. Your first action should be to read the manual for the function that you are using and check that you have used it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax mysqli_fetch_assoc is:

```
array mysqli_fetch_assoc ( mysqli_result $result )
```

Try (for PHP >=5.4):

```
$hits = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['hits'];
```

Answer (score -1):

From the codes, I see that you want to UPDATE the final records from hits.

```
$hitquery =  "SELECT * FROM $userstable where url = '$url'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $hitquery);
while(null !== ($hits= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $query2 = "UPDATE $userstable SET `hits` = hits+1 where url = '$url'";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for codes sir. but still generate **PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in** :)

Comment: it's okay :D I also learn much here to, upvote for you from me :p